# How do I get the "accordion" effect for input parameters in a Custom Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arctoolbox, python-script-tool

I want to get the "Accordion" effect you find in the some tools dialog boxes in my own Python Script tool.  I can't find anything on the ArcGIS Resources website about this.

An example is shown below:

[image: Screenshot of EBK tool dialog]

I am referring to the feature shown in "Additional Model Parameters" and the other additional toolsets.

Comment: The headings of your "accordian effect" are called Categories - the help link on the duplicate Q&A includes additional information about them.

Comment: @Midavalo that's what I was looking for.  Thank You!